# Clear user session on closing browser in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I want to clear the current session of a user on frontend in wordpress while closing the browser or tab. Currently when I login and close the browser, the user is already logged in.

I am using Wordpress 4.0 version. So please advise how I achieve this.

Comment: Why not just remove the option to check the "remember me" checkbox? This should solve it.

Comment: No I just want to delete user specific cookie. so that user should automatically loggout on closing the browser..

Comment: ...That's exactly what should happen if you leave the box unchecked.

Answer (score 0):

If you can include a JavaScript and know the exact wordpress cookie you can use following code to detect on close event and inside clear the cookie

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
       // Clear cookie here
      };
```

Comment: I am trying to add this code but its not working. I have set cookie name as "user_logged". And I have add the code as   document.cookie = "user_logged =; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT; path=/";

Comment: If you could use Jquery for this there is a library to manipulate cookies http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/

i saw this blog post for wordpress cookies
http://www.codecheese.com/2013/11/how-to-set-and-get-or-delete-cookies-with-wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the wp_logout function? Destroys the active session.